# Why is the king of Narnia a lion and not a human?

Tags: character

In the movie *The Chronicles of Narnia*, why did the producer make Aslan, The King of Narnia a lion, and not a human? Aslan is depicted as a talking lion and is described as the King of Beasts; the son of the Emperor-Over-the-Sea. If Aslan is a king of beasts, then why make him a proper lion and not like other beasts in the story, half lion and half human?

Comment: ermm... you do know this was a [book, or series of books](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Lion,_the_Witch_and_the_Wardrobe), first published 60 years ago & rather well-known for having a lion called Aslan as the king...?

Comment: Are you asking about the choice or perhaps the symbolism of using a talking Lion as opposed to a human (or anything else for that matter)? If so, then your question is not entirely clear and if not, it might work better as a symbolism question (which will have to relate to C.S. Lewis and the books) for a better non-opinion based answer. But really that Q might be better asked on  https://literature.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 11):

The Chronicles of Narnia is based on a book series, so it is C. S. Lewis who made this decision; not a film producer.

The reason Lewis chose Aslan to be a lion is likely because the books are intended to be an allegory of the Bible, and Aslan represents Jesus.

Jesus is referred to in the Bible as a Lion in Revelation 5:

> 5 Then one of the elders said to me, “Do not weep! See, the Lion of the tribe of Judah, the Root of David, has triumphed. He is able to open the scroll and its seven seals.”

Jesus as a Lion is a common metaphor in Christian belief.

In addition to this; it makes sense to use a lion, because lions are known as the king of the beasts.

Comment: Aslan itself means lion. I don't recall which language it is. But I doubt between Arabic, Persian and Turkish.